# MySQL group by between range

Tags: php, mysql

I have a rating table with 2 fields RatingID, UserID, RateValue
RateValue can be a 2 digit decimal

What I want is to group by result between range of RateValue and Count Records in that for example

RateValue between 0-1.5 should return 1, 1.6-2.5 will be 2, 2.6-3.5 will be 3, 3.6-4.5 will be 4, 4.6-5 will be 5

I want to group by between that range and get results like

OneStarRating - 2
TwoStarRating - 0 
ThreeStarRating - 3
FourStarRating - 1
FiveStarRating - 6

What I've tried now is this but not working

```
SELECT COUNT(RatingID) as TotalRecords, (IF(RateValue BETWEEN 0 AND 1.5,"OneStarRating",false) OR IF(RateValue BETWEEN 1.6 and 2.5,"TwoStarRating",false) OR IF(RateValue BETWEEN 2.6 and 3.5,"ThreeStarRating",false) OR IF(RateValue BETWEEN 3.6 and 4.5,"FourStarRating",false) OR IF(RateValue BETWEEN 4.6 and 5,"FiveStarRating",false)) as RateValue
FROM (`Ratings`)
GROUP BY RateValue
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  That is rather vague.

Comment: show sample data. You talk of concrete results without letting us visualize what the data is that go you there !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly have a sub query of unioned queries to bring back the ranges you are interested in:-

```
SELECT sub0.RateValue, COUNT(RatingID)
FROM Ratings
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 0 AS low_bound, 1.5 AS high_bound, "OneStarRating" AS RateValue
    UNION SELECT 1.6, 2.5, "TwoStarRating"
    UNION SELECT 2.6, 3.5, "ThreeStarRating"
    UNION SELECT 3.6, 4.5, "FourStarRating"
    UNION SELECT 4.6, 5, "FiveStarRating"
) sub0
ON Ratings.RateValue BETWEEN sub0.low_bound AND sub0.high_bound
GROUP BY sub0.RateValue
```

EDIT - To get a count of 0 where there are no records:-

```
SELECT sub0.RateValue, COUNT(RatingID)
FROM
(
    SELECT 0 AS low_bound, 1.5 AS high_bound, "OneStarRating" AS RateValue
    UNION SELECT 1.6, 2.5, "TwoStarRating"
    UNION SELECT 2.6, 3.5, "ThreeStarRating"
    UNION SELECT 3.6, 4.5, "FourStarRating"
    UNION SELECT 4.6, 5, "FiveStarRating"
) sub0
LEFT OUTER JOIN Ratings
ON Ratings.RateValue BETWEEN sub0.low_bound AND sub0.high_bound
GROUP BY sub0.RateValue
```

Comment: can we do something for values which is not exists but it will return 0 for example there's no record between 1.6 and 2.5 but it will return TwoStarRating as 0 ?

Comment: Should be. I have edited my answer to add a suggestion for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` statement (or a bunch of messy `if`s).  However, `round()` might be sufficient for what you want:

```
select round(RateValue) as rounded_ratevalue, count(*)
from ratings
group by rounded_ratevalue
order by rounded_ratevalue;
```

Comment: seems like best solution but just one question does round will round it to nearest or low or high ? for example I want 1.6-2.5 will be 2 and 2.6 to 3.5 will be 3

Comment: Round will round to the nearest, but that will mean a RateValue of 0 will not be counted with a RateValue of 0.6.

Comment: @MohitBumb . . . `round()` rounds down for a fractional part less than 0.5 and up for a fractional part greater than 0.5.  I think it round to an even number when the fractional part is exactly 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you :

```
SELECT COUNT(RatingID) as TotalRecords, 
CASE WHEN `RateValue` BETWEEN 0 AND 1.5   THEN "OneStarRating"
 WHEN `RateValue` BETWEEN 1.6 AND 2.5 THEN "TwoStarRating"
 WHEN `RateValue` BETWEEN 2.6 AND 3.5 THEN "TreeStarRating"
 WHEN `RateValue` BETWEEN 3.6 AND 4.5 THEN "FourStarRating"
 WHEN `RateValue` BETWEEN 4.6 AND 5.5 THEN "FiveStarRating"
 ELSE "NotRated"
END AS RatedValue
FROM `Ratings`
GROUP BY RatedValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it-

```
SELECT COUNT(ratevalue) AS TotalRecords, 
CASE WHEN ratevalue>= 0 AND ratevalue<= 1.5 THEN 'OneStarRating' WHEN ratevalue> 1.5 AND ratevalue<= 2.5 THEN 'TwoStarRating' WHEN ratevalue> 2.5 AND ratevalue<= 3.5 THEN 'ThreeStarRating' WHEN ratevalue> 3.5 AND ratevalue<= 4.5 THEN 'FourStarRating' WHEN ratevalue> 4.5 AND ratevalue<= 5 THEN 'FiveStarRating' ELSE 'None' END AS RateValue 
FROM Ratings 
GROUP BY RateValue;
```